# What is the default relaying policy for RBF double spend transactions?

Tags: network, relay, replace-by-fee

Let's say I broadcast a transation tx0 signaling [RBF](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0125.mediawiki) replaceability. Later on, I realize it has a small amount of fees, so I send another transaction tx1 that spends the same inputs than tx0, but this time with higher fees.

Which is the default bitcoind/bitcoin-qt behaviour regarding the relaying of tx1? Would all nodes broadcast the new version of the transaction or does the relay policy depend on the `mempoolreplacement` parameter? Do any special rules apply to the relaying of the replacement transaction?

I have seen that Peter Todd's RBF proposal included a [NODE_REPLACE_BY_FEE](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/93411077df9dab72b79316387e59ba683b2f0cdd) service bit. Is anything like this included in the current version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Nodes will only relay if `mempoolreplacement` hasn't set to false (most nodes probably do relay because the default is `true`).
2. There are several rules for accepting a replacement after [BIP125](https://bips.xyz/125) (check the BIP for more details). In general: `The replacement must pay greater fees than the transactions it replaces.`—Otherwise the bandwidth used by those conflicting transactions would not be paid for.
3. The mempool rules are relevant since nodes only relay transactions after accepting them to their mempool.